# Error con datatables y laravel 9

Tags: laravel, datatables, livewire

estoy implementando una tabla usando Datatables en laravel 9 y livewire, para ello utilizo datatables de este repositorio:
https://github.com/MedicOneSystems/livewire-datatables

Puedo mostrar la tabla, puede filtrar, ordenar, pero al momento de habilitar la exportación a través de su propiedad `exportable` y presionar el boton de export (se habilita al escribir la propiedad  `exportable`) me da un error:

```
Error Exception: Attempt to read property "preventExport" on int
```

y me marca el error en la siguiente linea:

```
    $request = Request::capture()
```

Mi modelo es este:

```
class Sucursal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $attributes = [
        'token' => "No set",
    ];
    protected $fillable=[
        'cod_sucursal',
        'description',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'codSys',
        'nit',
        'token',
        'codAmb',
        'modeWorkSys',

        'enabled'
    ];
}
```

Metodo run de Migración:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sucursals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('cod_sucursal')->unsigned();
            $table->string('description')->default('No description');
            $table->string('address')->default("No set");
            $table->string('phone',40)->default("No set");
            $table->string('codSys',30)->default("No set");
            $table->integer('nit')->default(0);
            $table->text('token')->nullable();

            $table->enum('codAmb',[1,2,3])->default(2);

            $table->enum('modeWorkSys',[1,2,3])->default(1);
            $table->string('codCategory',20)->default("No set"); 
            
         
            $table->boolean('enabled')->default(false);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Controlador:

```
use App\Models\Sucursal;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SucursalController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $sucursals=Sucursal::all();
        return view('sucursals.index',compact('sucursals'));
    }
}
```

y mi vista:

```
@extends('layouts.admin.layout')
@section('title',"List of Sucursals")

@section('container')

<livewire:datatable 
        model="App\Models\Sucursal"
       exportable /> 
    

@endsection
```

Alguien tuvo este problema y pudo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Antes de importar debes instalar laravel-excel
y seguir los pasos de aqui abajo:
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/366485)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).